# Google Ads URL parameters - potential violence for Facebook

Tags: facebook, url, google-ads-api

I have a pixel set on the website, and the pixel started notifying that it receives parameters that potentially violate users privacy. In test events I can see that pixel receives those parameters from Google Ads campaigns and pixel suggests removing from the string parameters like kw, pl, locphisical and device. I do not intend to waive these parameters from the URL's cause I need this info for Google Ads. But how I can deal with the pixel in this case?
Your expertise will be highly appreciated!

Tried to waive the parameters, it worked but doesn't suit, cause I need these parameters for Google campaigns